# Can't see Grafana images in Slack

Tags: slack, grafana

I set up a Slack notification channel in Grafana using a webhook as URL.
When I click "Send Test" I see this notification in my Slack channel:
[image]

However ordinary notifications are shown without images. I read Grafana's docs, but apparently I haven't understood it.

> If you want to include screenshots of the firing alerts in the slack messages you have to configure either the external image destination in Grafana, or a bot integration via Slack Apps. Follow Slack’s guide to set up a bot integration and use the token provided https://api.slack.com/bot-users, which starts with “xoxb”.

Can someone guide me through it? I created a new bot and generated a token for it (starts with xoxb as requested) but how do I keep going from there?

Comment: https://grafana.com/docs/alerting/notifications/#external-image-store this may help

Answer (score 1):

Please assign this permission in your Slack app then try:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to `<grafana_host>/alerting/notification/new` (or click the top-left Menu icon, select "Alerting", select "Notification Channels", click the green "New Channel" button). You should get the page in the screenshot below.

Do the following steps:

- Set "Name" for the channel.
- Set the channel "Type" to `Slack`.
- **Check "Include image" option.**
- In "Slack settings", set "URL" to incoming
  webhook you created in Slack.
- Set "Token" to bot token generated for
  bot.

And voila!

[image: Screenshot to Create Slack notification channel in Grafana]

**Update**

> Ability to configure a Slack token was added in Grafana version **4.6.0**

Comment: I'm on Grafana 4.4.3 and not seeing the Token field (I'm assuming this was added after 4.4.3). What version are you on?

Comment: I'm on Grafana version 4.6.0

Comment: I'm not sure that you require a Token in any case for [Slack incoming webhook](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks)

Comment: this did not solve the problem. images are still not showing up in the slacl

Comment: This isn't what he asked, he asked for "how to see graph image in slack"

Comment: This was what OP asked. I wrote what worked for me at the time.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't mentioned by OP but if your target Slack channel is a private channel, you'll also need to ensure that you've added the bot to the private channel so that it is able upload an image to it.

You can do this by viewing the channel's details, clicking "More" and then "Add apps".  On the screen that shows up, you should be able to search for the bot that you created and click the "Add" button aside it.

Good luck!